# where can i find httpd.conf or apache2.conf file or ./configure file so that i can do proxy setting in apache-tomcat-7.0.62?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, proxy

I have downloaded and and unpack **apache-tomcat-7.0.62.tar.gz**. Every thing is working correctly but now i want some proxy setting for url (so that i remove port number from url and make some special change in url format).

I go through apache-tomcat documentation for proxy settings on

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

They mention about **./configure** file and **httpd.conf** file but i am unable to find these files.

I am using **ubuntu 14.04 LTS** . Please suggest me where can i find these files and if these files are not available in this package then suggest me how can i do proxy settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your apache server is up and running, then you can use ps command to find the location

ps -ef|grep apache

from the install location, you can search

find  -name httpd.conf

Usually it will be in /etc

Comment: I run above command and find following : - sushant   3308  2011  1 19:12 pts/0    00:00:17 /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.62 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.62

Comment: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
sushant   3557  3488  0 19:28 pts/10   00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache @slowhandblues

Comment: can you search using find in /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/

Answer (score 0):

Actually i did mistake in understanding concepts,  **httpd.conf** file is available with **apache** server and i was finding it in **apache-tomcat-7.0.62** which is a **tomcat server**.